# Modify MVC project to locate Controllers on my feature based custom Path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 project where I want to apply the "Feature-Driven design" by Jimmy Bogard, showed on this [post](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/07/02/ndc-talk-on-solid-in-slices-not-layers-video-online/). But I want to modify his design to separate the features into another sub-division by Role, so my plan is to have my ASP.NET MVC project structured in this way:

`MyRoleFeatureProject
    ├── Roles
    │   ├── Manager
    │   │   ├── Features
    │   │   │   ├── Index
    │   │   │   │  ├── Index.cshtml
    │   │   │   │  ├── Index.js
    │   │   │   │  ├── IndexController.cs
    │   │   │   ├── Invoice
    │   │   │   │  ├── Invoice.cshtml
    │   │   │   │  ├── Invoice.js
    │   │   │   │  ├── InvoiceController.cs
    │   ├── Admin
    │   │   ├── Features
    │   │   │   ├── Index
    │   │   │   │  ├── Index.cshtml
    │   │   │   │  ├── Index.js
    │   │   │   │  ├── IndexController.cs
    │   │   │   ├── UserManagement
    │   │   │   │  ├── UserManagement.cshtml
    │   │   │   │  ├── UserManagement.js
    │   │   │   │  ├── UserManagementController.cs
    │   ├── Operator
    │   │   ├── Features
    │   │   │   ├── Index
    │   │   │   │  ├── Index.cshtml
    │   │   │   │  ├── Index.js
    │   │   │   │  ├── IndexController.cs
    │   │   │   ├── Shipping
    │   │   │   │  ├── Shipping.cshtml
    │   │   │   │  ├── Shipping.js
    │   │   │   │  ├── ShippingController.cs
    │   ├── Anonymous
    │   │   ├── Features
    │   │   │   ├── LogIn
    │   │   │   │  ├── LogIn.cshtml
    │   │   │   │  ├── LogIn.js
    │   │   │   │  ├── LogInController.cs
    │   │   │   ├── Register
    │   │   │   │  ├── Register.cshtml
    │   │   │   │  ├── Register.js
    │   │   │   │  ├── RegisterController.cs
    │   │   │   ├── ForgotPassword
    │   │   │   │  ├── ForgotPassword.cshtml
    │   │   │   │  ├── ForgotPassword.js
    │   │   │   │  ├── ForgotPasswordController.cs
    │   ├── Shared
    │   │   ├── _ManagerLayout.cshtml
    │   │   ├── _AdminLayout.cshtml
    │   │   ├── _OperatorLayout.cshtml
    │   │   ├── _AnonymousLayout.cshtml
    │   ├── _ViewStart.cshtml
    │   ├── Web.config
    ├── Images
    ├── Scripts
    ├── Styles
    ├── Web.config`

I've followed some online guides and I understand I need to create a class that inherits from *DefaultControllerFactory* for controller's custom location and also another one that inherits from *RazorViewEngine* for view's custom location, but I'm not able to configure them to match the location I'm showing you in my tree diagram, that's why I'm asking for your help.

I'm not expert in ASP.NET MVC and this is my first try to implement this design on my way to learn new things. I really want to get this working.

Thanks for your guidance.

**Update 1**

After seeing the answer from @IvanGritsenko I've noticed that every controller must be able to handle multiple actions (for that feature) and also that many roles could have features (controllers) with the same name, for example "Index", every role will have an Index that will be a custom "dashboard" (showing custom information for that role).

Thinking about that, I think it will be great if:

1) By someway I could resolve the Controller's location after the user was logged In. So if I look for Index controller it could look for it inside the specific role folder.

Or

2) The routing is modified to match the pattern /Role/Controller/Feature after the user was logged In.

Comment: Override `RazorViewEngine.FindView`, `RazorViewEngine.FindPartialView`

Comment: @IvanGritsenko I already did it but I can not figure out the right form of writing the location format for controllers and views

Comment: Based on the ContosoUniversity example that Jimmy Bogard provided (https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversity/blob/master/src/ContosoUniversity/Infrastructure/FeatureViewLocationRazorViewEngine.cs), his routes are simply `Features/{controller}/{action}`

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1. Create custom view engine.**

```
public class MyViewEngine : RazorViewEngine 
{
    public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
    {
        var roleName = controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("role");
        var controllerName = controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        var path = string.Format("~/Roles/{0}/Features/{1}/{1}.cshtml", roleName, controllerName);
        var layoutPath = string.Format("/Roles/Shared/_{0}Layout.cshtml", controllerName);
        return new ViewEngineResult(new RazorView(controllerContext, path, layoutPath, false, null), this);
    }

    public override ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialViewName, bool useCache)
    {
        var roleName = controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("role");
        var controllerName = controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        var path = string.Format("~/Roles/{0}/Features/{1}/{1}.cshtml", roleName, controllerName);
        return new ViewEngineResult(new RazorView(controllerContext, path, null, false, null), this);
    }
}
```

**Step 2. Register custom view engine in Global.asax.**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyViewEngine());
}
```

**Step 3. Change default route in `RouteConfig`**

```
routes.MapRoute( name: "Default", url: "{role}/{controller}", defaults: new { action = "Index" });
```

**Example of Controller**

```
public class UserManagementController : Controller
{
    // GET: UserManagement
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Example of url to call  `Index` action of `UserManagementController`.**

http://domainname.com/Admin/UserManagement

Comment: With this approach is it possible that a Controller have N actions, lets say the LogInController has: 1 action to draw the view (default get), 1 action to validate user's data before submit (POST called by ajax), and finally 1 action that will submit the form (POST called by ajax), is that possible? As I understand your solution requires only 1 action per Controller and calling something like site/LogInController/Validate will not be valid

Comment: At this point I didn't take into account Actions. They may be easily added. Do you want to be able to use arbitrary View names like `return View('SomeView')`? Also what is the purpose of `IndexController`s? This solution actually will not work against many controllers of the same name. No way to call `IndexController` now.

Comment: Yes, Index Will be a custom main dashboard (pending actions, alerts, etc) for each role, so it Will be different in actions and ui